# Why won't Ruby methods mutate the original array?

Tags: ruby, methods, shuffle

I'm creating a game so as to practice some basic Ruby. In my blackjack game, I've created a deck of cards to draw from. The only way that I've managed to mix up the array, draw from that array and remove two cards from the original cards array is as follows:

```
player_cards = cards.shuffle!.shift(2)
```

I tried to use shift and pop along with shuffle like so:

```
player_cards = cards.shuffle.shift
player_cards = cards.shuffle.pop
```

In IRB, if I use pop and shift without shuffle, the array I'm trying to pull from (array of hashes) removes those cards from the deck. As soon as I add shuffle, the cards are no longer removed from the deck permanently. I have to use shuffle! in order to complete my task.

What I want to know is, why doesn't pop and shift work as expected with shuffle? My rudimentary understanding of chaining in Ruby is that the cards array is first shuffled and returned and then an element in the array is removed.

My only thought as to what my error might be is that shuffle shuffles the array and returns a shuffled array, but not the original cards array. When I pop or shift one or two cards from that shuffled array, it's the array returned by shuffle, not the original array of cards. Is that correct?

Comment: sorry I can't understand the problem. can you point me to it?

Comment: @Aleksey the problem is clearly stated, I do not see any reason to clarify anything more.

Comment: sorry I am a little ill today maybe it's because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a significant difference between [`cards.shuffle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) and [`cards.shuffle!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle-21) (banged version.)

The former *creates a new array*, and the latter *mutates the original one*.

That said, your latter code `shift`s and `pop`s from the *copy* of the original array, produced by `shuffle`.

Comment: That's what I thought might be the issue, but I was not 100% sure. Is there a great Stackoverflow question about Ruby methods and how they work when chained together like I'm doing above? It would help solve future issues if I had a detailed understanding of the chaining process.

Comment: I am not sure about the SO question, but chaining methods is as simple as chaining anything else: the method receives an input and returns a value. When chained, the next method is being called on what was returned. Thas simple. Consider `'a'.ord.to_s.split('')`. `a.ord` returns `97` ⇒ `97.to_s` returns `"97"` ⇒ `"97".split('')` returns `["9", "7"]` etc. What had you confused, is mutating of the original object. In general, there is a goodwill rule: if a method mutates the receiver, it has an ending bang `!` in the name. Otherwise the method would likely produce a new instance. Hope it helps.